# Como configurar um projeto com JUnit para conseguir construir injetar corretamente o EntityManager?

Tags: java, demoiselle, junit

Tenho uma aplicação legada JSF/Demoiselle 2.4 que não apresentava a boa prática de construir testes unitários. De forma a satisfazer novos requisitos, tenho implementações a fazer e pretendo construí-las fazendo uso de TDD.

No entanto, ao escrever meu primeiro *test case* tive problemas com a execução de uma consulta Hibernate por que o `EntityManager` não é injetado no objeto `DAO` (que é um derivado de `JPACrud`).

Na base da exception stack tenho:

```
Caused by: javax.naming.NoInitialContextException: Need to specify class name in environment or system property, or as an applet parameter, or in an application resource file:  java.naming.factory.initial
    at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getInitialContext(Unknown Source)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.getDefaultInitCtx(Unknown Source)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.getURLOrDefaultInitCtx(Unknown Source)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.getNameParser(Unknown Source)
    at org.hibernate.service.jndi.internal.JndiServiceImpl.parseName(JndiServiceImpl.java:86)
    ... 104 more
```

O arquivo `persistence.xml` próprio para o JUnit está configurado da mesma forma que o da aplicação (onde tudo funciona). Acredito que esteja me faltando algum detalhe, mas no momento não sou capaz de identificar.

Fico agradecido com qualquer auxílio!

## Atualização

Após alguns estudos, percebi que poderia configurar a `persistence.xml` para não mais fazer uso de um *DataSource* configurado no JBoss e que o correto é configurar os parâmetros de conexão diretamente. Após fazer isso e atualizar o meu `pom.xml` para incluir o suporte ao driver `JDBC` para o `JUnit`, a exceção mudou para:

```
Caused by: javax.naming.NoInitialContextException: Need to specify class name in environment or system property, or as an applet parameter, or in an application resource file:  java.naming.factory.initial
    at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getInitialContext(Unknown Source)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.getDefaultInitCtx(Unknown Source)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.getURLOrDefaultInitCtx(Unknown Source)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.getNameParser(Unknown Source)
    at org.hibernate.service.jndi.internal.JndiServiceImpl.parseName(JndiServiceImpl.java:86)
    ... 79 more
```

Assim, acho que a situação evoluiu, mas ainda preciso solucionar este caso!

Alguém tem alguma dica?

## Atualização 2

Como solicitado, seguem tanto a classe de testes quanto o `pom.xml`.

### Classe de testes

```
package br.ufpr.frequencia.scheduler;

import javax.inject.Inject;

import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.BeforeClass;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

import br.gov.frameworkdemoiselle.junit.DemoiselleRunner;

@RunWith(DemoiselleRunner.class)
public class SchedulerTests {

    @Inject
    FrequenciaScheduler scheduler;

    @BeforeClass
    public static void setUpBeforeClass() throws Exception {
    }

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
    }

    @After
    public void tearDown() throws Exception {
    }

    @Test
    public void shouldAtualizarCarreiraEscalaComPredispostos() {
        // Arranje

        // Act
        scheduler.atualizarCarreiraEscalasDePredispostos();

        // Assert
    }

}
```

### POM.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>br.ufpr</groupId>
    <artifactId>frequencia</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-Dev</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <name></name>
    <description></description>
    <url></url>

    <parent>
        <groupId>br.gov.frameworkdemoiselle</groupId>
        <artifactId>demoiselle-jsf-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.1</version>
    </parent>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>br.ufpr</groupId>
          <artifactId>core</artifactId>
          <version>1.0.8</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- SECURITY - CAS -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>br.ufpr</groupId>
            <artifactId>Security_SCA_CAS_EJB2</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jdom</groupId>
            <artifactId>jdom2</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>br.gov.frameworkdemoiselle</groupId>
            <artifactId>demoiselle-jpa</artifactId>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>br.gov.frameworkdemoiselle</groupId>
            <artifactId>demoiselle-jta</artifactId>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
            <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
            <version>5.0</version><!--$NO-MVN-MAN-VER$ -->
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.primefaces.extensions</groupId>
            <artifactId>primefaces-extensions</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.primefaces.themes</groupId>
          <artifactId>cupertino</artifactId>
          <version>1.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>br.gov.frameworkdemoiselle.component</groupId>
            <artifactId>demoiselle-junit</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-envers</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.7.Final</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>antlr</groupId>
                    <artifactId>antlr</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.antlr</groupId>
            <artifactId>antlr</artifactId>
            <version>3.5.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-beanutils</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-beanutils</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>br.ufpr</groupId>
          <artifactId>sigepeservice-client</artifactId>
          <version>1.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>br.ufpr</groupId>
          <artifactId>sieservice-client</artifactId>
          <version>1.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>br.ufpr</groupId>
          <artifactId>sigeuservice-client</artifactId>
          <version>1.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.as</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-as-ejb-client-bom</artifactId>
            <version>7.1.3.Final</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>br.ufpr.doodle</groupId>
            <artifactId>doodle-consumertool</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
            <artifactId>ojdbc14</artifactId>
            <version>10.2.0.5.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <repositories>
        <!-- Repositorio interno DSI UFPR -->
        <repository>
            <id>nexus</id>
            <name>Nexus</name>
            <url>http://homologa3.cce.ufpr.br:8080/nexus/content/groups/public</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
            <releases>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </releases>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
</project>
```

## Atualização 3

Segue conforme solicitado.

### persistence.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="xxx-ds" transaction-type="JTA">
        <!-- Várias classes -->
        <class>br.xxx.yyy.domain.zzz</class>

        <properties>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="XXXXXXX" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="*******" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@server.service.br:1521:kk" />

            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
            <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true" />
            <property name="hibernate.transaction.jta.platform"
                value="org.hibernate.service.jta.platform.internal.JBossAppServerJtaPlatform" />
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect" />

            <!-- Envers properties -->
            <property name="org.hibernate.envers.audit_table_prefix" value=""/>
            <property name="org.hibernate.envers.audit_table_suffix" value="_AUD"/>
            <property name="org.hibernate.envers.revision_field_name" value="versao"/>
            <property name="org.hibernate.envers.revision_type_field_name" value="operacao"/>
            <property name="org.hibernate.envers.store_data_at_delete" value="true"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Comment: Pode postar a classe de testes?

Comment: também o pom.xml e o persistence.xml de testes.

Comment: @saito: detalhes adicionados

Comment: @Saito: adicionei o código do `persistence.xml`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Verifique se o persistence.xml para testes está em: /src/**test**/resources/META-INF com as configurações de conexão local e declaração das classes de entidade.
Ex:

```
<persistence version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">

 <persistence-unit name="bookmark-ds" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <class>org.demoiselle.bookmark.domain.Bookmark</class>
    <properties>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver" />
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="sa" />
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="" />
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:hsqldb:mem:." />
        <property name="eclipselink.logging.level" value="FINE" />
        <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation" value="create-tables" />
        <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation.output-mode" value="database" />
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Não será o mesmo que está em /src/**main**/resources/META-INF

Comment: Obrigado pela informação, mas como coloquei em uma atualização da pergunta, já havia me dado conta deste detalhe e fiz a alteração, o que de fato alterou a situação de erro, trocando de um para outro. No entanto, ainda existe erro!

Comment: Olá, faltou o persistence.xml. E como vc está usando JTA no projeto, confira se o demoiselle.properties de testes /src/test/resources esta configurado para usar JPA. Atualize o demoiselle-junit para 2.3.1 também.

Comment: No seu persistence.xml você está configurando para JTA (transaction-type="JTA") e no teste com JUnit não irá funcionar. Você deve utilizar RESOURCE_LOCAL. Outra recomendação que faria, é o de não utilizar a conexão com o banco de dados oracle. Se fôssemos seguir à risca o conceito de teste unitário, sequer deveríamos utilizar um banco, mas apenas "mocks". O teste com o uso de banco caracterizaria teste integrado. Para facilitar a construção, optamos por utilizar o Hsqldb que é um banco bastante simples nos testes.

Comment: Assim podem ser criados testes que não sejam afetados por características do banco. Mas não impede que vc teste com o Oracle, mas terá que configurar sem JTA.

Comment: Outra justificativa para uso do hsqldb, é que se houvesse ambiente de integração contínua (comum nos nossos ambientes internos), seria ainda mais recomendado não usar conexão externa, pois se o servidor estiver fora do ar, os testes falhariam. De forma "embarcada" como no uso do Hsqldb não haveria esse risco.

Comment: parece que a última recomendação a respeito do tipo da transação (RESOURCE_LOCAL) era o que faltava para que tudo ficasse a contento. Depois dessa etapa faltou também remover a exclusão da importação do ANTLR junto com o Hinernate, no POM.XML. Agora os testes já executam. Gostaria de agradecer pela tua disposição em ajudar!

Comment: De nada Alex, estamos aqui para ajudar.

Comment: Depois de muito tempo retomei a questão. Tudo está funcionando em meus testes, exceto situações de gravação de dados. O que ocorre é que nenhuma transação está sendo criada e commitada. Como resultado, certas situações de teste que considerar estão falahando nos testes. Alguma ideia do que está faltando?